# Wrong order of execution in Resolution Center crash report

Tags: ios, swift, crash

My app got rejected from the app store because there is a button that causes it to crash when pressed on an iPad. I don't have an iPad, and the bug is unreproducible on any of the iPad simulators. Here's the crash report the Resolution Center sent me:

```
{"app_name":"xxx","timestamp":"2018-05-23 14:18:37.70 -0700","app_version":"0.4.5","slice_uuid":"f7e0571c-a2a9-313c-ab7b-9a9109670ff2","adam_id":1387669409,"build_version":"1","bundleID":"com.b.xxx","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 11.3.1 (15E302)","incident_id":"D5ADA937-9FAF-479B-A925-7B127B5E0C44","name":"xxx"}
Incident Identifier: D5ADA937-9FAF-479B-A925-7B127B5E0C44
CrashReporter Key:   cac3035154ad4b589b77fd30cfea229fc2cfaf20
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             xxx [1949]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/FD86FF84-2DDF-4DFA-B23D-703D4A08316B/xxx.app/xxx
Identifier:          com.b.xxx
Version:             1 (0.4.5)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.b.xxx [1153]


Date/Time:           2018-05-23 14:18:37.5753 -0700
Launch Time:         2018-05-23 14:18:31.9754 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.3.1 (15E302)
Baseband Version:    6.55.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000180b03644
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBDISPATCH: trying to lock recursively

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180b03644 _dispatch_gate_wait_slow$VARIANT$mp + 180
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180b04334 dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$mp + 132
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180b04334 dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$mp + 132
3   xxx                             0x00000001006cc6ec specialized static TextFieldFactory.manufacture(for:with:) + 2868972 (TextFieldFactory.swift:13)
4   xxx                             0x00000001006535ac _T09xxx22GRADEDISPLAY_MAX_WIDTH12CoreGraphics7CGFloatVvpfiAEycfU_ + 2373036 (DimensionConstants.swift:0)
5   xxx                             0x00000001006532b8 globalinit_33_D344213E1027291683078D92DF0D6E22_func214 + 2372280 (DimensionConstants.swift:220)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180b00ae4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180b042ec dispatch_once_f$VARIANT$mp + 60
8   xxx                             0x00000001006cc6ec specialized static TextFieldFactory.manufacture(for:with:) + 2868972 (TextFieldFactory.swift:13)
9   xxx                             0x00000001006cac10 static TextFieldFactory.manufacture(for:with:) + 2862096 (TextFieldFactory.swift:0)
10  xxx                             0x0000000100614f2c _T09xxx04EditA4ViewC5titleAA9TextFieldCvgAFycfU_ + 2117420 (EditClassView.swift:26)
11  xxx                             0x000000010060ff90 EditClassView.beginInit() + 2097040 (EditClassView.swift:24)
12  xxx                             0x00000001006bc970 MView.init(sizeConstraint:) + 2804080 (MView.swift:0)
13  xxx                             0x0000000100614934 EditClassView.init(cCreateSemester:clss:sizeConstraint:) + 2115892 (EditClassView.swift:237)
14  xxx                             0x00000001007184f8 specialized CCreateSemester.createCreateCourseView(_:) + 3179768 (CCreateSemester.swift:667)
15  xxx                             0x000000010071393c CCreateSemester.setupNewSemester() + 3160380 (CCreateSemester.swift:594)
16  xxx                             0x000000010071030c CCreateSemester.viewDidLoad() + 3146508 (CCreateSemester.swift:0)
17  xxx                             0x0000000100711674 @objc CCreateSemester.viewDidLoad+ 3151476 () + 28
18  UIKit                           0x000000018adeaee0 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1020
19  UIKit                           0x000000018ae98e98 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 76
20  UIKit                           0x000000018ae98354 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 172
21  UIKit                           0x000000018ae97c90 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 1164
22  UIKit                           0x000000018ae97720 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 164
23  UIKit                           0x000000018ae8b424 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 188
24  UIKit                           0x000000018ade3770 -[UIView+ 309104 (CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1420
25  QuartzCore                      0x000000018538525c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 184
26  QuartzCore                      0x00000001853893ec CA::Layer::layout_if_needed+ 1209324 (CA::Transaction*) + 324
27  QuartzCore                      0x00000001852f5aa0 CA::Context::commit_transaction+ 604832 (CA::Transaction*) + 320
28  QuartzCore                      0x000000018531d5d0 CA::Transaction::commit+ 767440 () + 580
29  QuartzCore                      0x000000018531e450 CA::Transaction::observer_callback+ 771152 (__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92
30  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811b6910 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
31  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811b4238 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412
32  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811b4884 __CFRunLoopRun + 1436
33  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001810d4da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
34  GraphicsServices                0x00000001830b7020 GSEventRunModal + 100
35  UIKit                           0x000000018b0b578c UIApplicationMain + 236
36  xxx                             0x00000001004179b8 main + 31160 (PercentBasedUnequalField.swift:12)
37  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000180b65fc0 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180c95d84 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e33eb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e33b08 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180c95d84 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e33eb4 _pthread_wqthread + 928
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e33b08 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180c95d84 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e340a0 _pthread_wqthread + 1420
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e33b08 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e33b04 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180c73e08 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180c73c80 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811b6e40 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811b4908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001810d4da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5   Foundation                      0x0000000181b49674 -[NSRunLoop+ 34420 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x0000000181b4951c -[NSRunLoop+ 34076 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 148
7   UIKit                           0x000000018ad9a7e4 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x0000000181c59efc __NSThread__start__ + 1040
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e35220 _pthread_body + 272
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e35110 _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e33b10 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e33b04 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7 name:  RLMRealm notification listener
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180c7834c kevent + 8
1   Realm                           0x0000000100a05a80 realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::listen() + 88704 (external_commit_helper.cpp:203)
2   Realm                           0x0000000100a063ec std::__1::__async_func<realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator&)::$_0>::operator()() + 91116 (future:2323)
3   Realm                           0x0000000100a06374 std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator&)::$_0> >::__execute() + 90996 (future:1041)
4   Realm                           0x0000000100a06524 std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator&)::$_0> >::*)(), std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator&)::$_0> >*> >(void*, void*) + 91428 (thread:354)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e35220 _pthread_body + 272
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e35110 _pthread_body + 0
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e33b10 thread_start + 4

Thread 8 name:  RLMRealm notification listener
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180c7834c kevent + 8
1   Realm                           0x0000000100a05a80 realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::listen() + 88704 (external_commit_helper.cpp:203)
2   Realm                           0x0000000100a063ec std::__1::__async_func<realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator&)::$_0>::operator()() + 91116 (future:2323)
3   Realm                           0x0000000100a06374 std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator&)::$_0> >::__execute() + 90996 (future:1041)
4   Realm                           0x0000000100a06524 std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator&)::$_0> >::*)(), std::__1::__async_assoc_state<void, std::__1::__async_func<realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator&)::$_0> >*> >(void*, void*) + 91428 (thread:354)
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e35220 _pthread_body + 272
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e35110 _pthread_body + 0
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e33b10 thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x00000001007cdd68   x1: 0x0000000000000301   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x00000001007654a0   x5: 0x0000000000000011   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x00000001c8041ce0
    x8: 0x0000000000000003   x9: 0x0000000000000301  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x0000000000000000
   x12: 0x0000000000000001  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000000000000001
   x16: 0x0000000180b042b0  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x00000000ffffffff  x21: 0x00000001007cdd68  x22: 0x0000000000000303  x23: 0x0000000000000001
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0x0000000101534280  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000000000001
   x28: 0x0000000000000001   fp: 0x000000016f9eb140   lr: 0x0000000180b04334
    sp: 0x000000016f9eb120   pc: 0x0000000180b03644 cpsr: 0x60000000
```

Moving up from Line 11 Thread 0 here is the code execution:

Line 11: `EditClassView.beginInit()`

```
class EditClassView: MStackView {

    // Parent implementation does nothing
    override func beginInit() {

        // First time `title` is referenced. It's lazy, so it's initialized here
        title.text = clss.getTitle()

        // Crashes before here
        ...
    }
}
```

Line 10: Initialization of local `title` property in `EditClassView.title's` lazy initializer:

```
lazy private(set) var title: TextField = {

    let title = TF.manufacture(for: .allPurpose, with: TParams(textSize: 21, inputView: nil, placeholder: "Class Title"))

    // Crashes before here
    ...
}()
```

Line 9: I think this is just referring to the `TextFieldFactory.manufacture(for:with:)` reference, and not the actual execution of the function itself:

Line 8: I'm not sure what this is referring to. It appears to just be the `TextFieldFactory.TextFieldParams` typealias because that's what's on `TextFieldFactory.swift:13`:

```
typealias TParams = TextFieldFactory.TextFieldParams

// Here is the definition    
class TextFieldParams {

    static let DEFAULT_TEXT: String? = nil
    static let DEFAULT_FONT_NAME = "poiretone-regular"
    static let DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE = MEDIUM_TEXT_SIZE
    static let DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR = UIColor.black
    static let DEFAULT_TINT_COLOR = UIColor.black
    static let DEFAULT_TEXT_ALIGNMENT = NSTextAlignment.center
    static let DEFAULT_USES_AUTORESIZING_MASK = true
    static let DEFAULT_INPUT_VIEW = TextFieldFactory.EMPTY_INPUT_VIEW
    static let DEFAULT_PLACEHOLDER: String? = nil
    static let DEFAULT_ADJUST_WIDTH_WITH_TEXT = false
    static let DEFAULT_MIN_WIDTH: CGFloat? = nil
    static let DEFAULT_MAX_WIDTH: CGFloat? = nil
    static let DEFAULT_EMPTY_WIDTH: CGFloat? = nil

    let text: String?
    let fontName: String
    let textSize: CGFloat
    let textColor: UIColor
    let tintColor: UIColor
    let textAlignment: NSTextAlignment
    let translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: Bool
    let inputView: UIView?
    let placeholder: String?
    let adjustWidthWithText: Bool
    let minWidth: CGFloat?
    let maxWidth: CGFloat?
    let emptyWidth: CGFloat?

    var font: UIFont {   return UIFont(name: fontName, size: textSize)!   }

    init(text: String? = DEFAULT_TEXT,
         fontName: String = DEFAULT_FONT_NAME,
         textSize: CGFloat = DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE,
         textColor: UIColor = DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR,
         tintColor: UIColor = DEFAULT_TINT_COLOR,
         textAlignment: NSTextAlignment = DEFAULT_TEXT_ALIGNMENT,
         translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: Bool = DEFAULT_USES_AUTORESIZING_MASK,
         inputView: UIView? = DEFAULT_INPUT_VIEW,
         placeholder: String? = DEFAULT_PLACEHOLDER,
         adjustWidthWithText: Bool = DEFAULT_ADJUST_WIDTH_WITH_TEXT,
         minWidth: CGFloat? = DEFAULT_MIN_WIDTH,
         maxWidth: CGFloat? = DEFAULT_MAX_WIDTH,
         emptyWidth: CGFloat? = DEFAULT_EMPTY_WIDTH
        ) {

        self.text = text
        self.fontName = fontName
        self.textSize = textSize
        self.textColor = textColor
        self.tintColor = tintColor
        self.textAlignment = textAlignment
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints
        self.inputView = inputView
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self.adjustWidthWithText = adjustWidthWithText
        self.minWidth = minWidth
        self.maxWidth = maxWidth
        self.emptyWidth = emptyWidth
    }
}
```

Now here's where I get lost. Line 7 and 6 don't refer to my code at all, so I'm not sure what it's doing but next thing you know one of my global constants --`GRADEDISPLAY_MAX_WIDTH` -- is getting initialized on Line 5. And bear in mind that it has nothing to do with `EditClassView` at all let alone `EditClassView.title`.

But before I show its initialization, there is a link. `GRADEDISPLAY_MAX_WIDTH` is referenced in `TF.manufacture(for:with:)`, but you'll see that the function is just one big `switch` block, and `GRADEDISPLAY_MAX_WIDTH` is not referenced in the case we should be executing in which is odd. If you look back to Line 10, you'll see the relevant case is `.allPurpose`, all the way at the end of the function:

```
static func manufacture(for textFieldPurpose: TextFieldPurpose, with params: TextFieldParams = TextFieldParams()) -> TextField {

    switch textFieldPurpose {

    case .notifyingTimeField:

        var ntf = makeNotifyingFocusableTimeField(with: params as! NotifyingFocusableTimeFieldParams)
        ntf.frame.size.width = CGFloat.timeFieldWidth
        ntf.underline()

        return ntf

    case .timeField:

        var ftf = makeFocusableTimeField(with: params as! FocusableTimeFieldParams)
        ftf.frame.size.width = CGFloat.timeFieldWidth
        ftf.underline()

        return ftf

    case .gradingCategoryTitle:

        var tf = makeUnderlineTextField(with: UnderlineTextFieldParams(edgeInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, AC_TITLE_DEFAULT_SIDE_INSET, UnderlineLabel.DEFAULT_BOTTOM_INSET, AC_TITLE_DEFAULT_SIDE_INSET),
                                                                       text: params.text,
                                                                       textSize: LARGE_TEXT_SIZE,
                                                                       inputView: nil,
                                                                       adjustWidthWithText: true,
                                                                       maxWidth: params.maxWidth)
        )
        tf.underline()

        return tf

    case .whereTextField:

        var tf = makeUnderlineTextField(with: UnderlineTextFieldParams(inputView: nil,
                                                                       adjustWidthWithText: true,
                                                                       minWidth: WHERE_TEXTFIELD_MIN_WIDTH,
                                                                       maxWidth: params.maxWidth)
        )
        tf.underline()

        return tf

    case .notifyingDateField:

        var ndf = makeNotifyingFocusableDateField(with: params as! ContextualFocusableParams)
        ndf.frame.size.width = CGFloat.timeFieldWidth
        ndf.underline()

        return ndf

    case .percentTotalField, .percentEachField, .percentUnequalField, .pointsTotalField, .pointsEachField, .pointsUnequalField, .percentExamTotalField, .percentEachExamField, .percentFinalField, .pointsExamTotalField, .pointsEachExamField, .pointsFinalField:

        guard let params = params as? ContextualFocusableParams else {

            fatalError("A ContextualFocusableParams must be passed in order to manufacture a FocusableWeightField")
        }

        var f = makeFocusableWeightField(for: textFieldPurpose, with: ContextualFocusableParams(context: params.context,
                                                                                                adjustWidthWithText: true,
                                                                                                minWidth: CGFloat.timeFieldWidth)
        )
        f.underline()

        return f

    case .customTitleField:

        let edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, CUSTOM_TITLE_SIDE_INSET, UnderlineLabel.DEFAULT_BOTTOM_INSET, CUSTOM_TITLE_SIDE_INSET)
        var tf = makeUnderlineTextField(with: UnderlineTextFieldParams(edgeInsets: edgeInsets,
                                                                       inputView: nil,
                                                                       placeholder: params.placeholder,
                                                                       adjustWidthWithText: true,
                                                                       minWidth: params.minWidth,
                                                                       maxWidth: params.maxWidth,
                                                                       emptyWidth: params.emptyWidth)
        )
        tf.underline()

        return tf

    case .gradeField:

        let tf = initializedTextField(textField: PercentSuffixedTextField(),
                                      params: TParams(text: params.text,
                                                      textSize: AV_GRADE_TEXT_SIZE,
                                                      textColor: UIColor.defaultTextColor,
                                                      inputView: nil)
        )
        tf.frame.size = CGSize(width: GRADEDISPLAY_MAX_WIDTH, height: GV_HEIGHT)
        tf.isEnabled = false
        tf.keyboardType = .numberPad

        return tf

    case .fractionField:

        let tf = makeTextField(with: TParams(text: params.text,
                                             textSize: AV_GRADE_TEXT_SIZE,
                                             textColor: UIColor.defaultTextColor,
                                             inputView: nil)
        )
        tf.frame.size.width = GRADEDISPLAY_MAX_WIDTH
        tf.isEnabled = false
        tf.keyboardType = .numberPad

        return tf

    case .assessmentTitle:

        let tf = makeTextField(with: TParams(text: params.text,
                                             textSize: AV_TITLE_TEXT_SIZE,
                                             textColor: UIColor.defaultTextColor,
                                             placeholder: String.classTitlePlaceholder,
                                             adjustWidthWithText: true)
        )
        tf.isEnabled = false

        return tf

    case .weightField:

        let tf = initializedTextField(textField: PercentSuffixedTextField(adjustWidthWithText: true, minWidth: params.minWidth),
                                      params: TParams(text: params.text,
                                                      textSize: params.textSize,
                                                      textAlignment: .right,
                                                      inputView: nil)
        )
        tf.keyboardType = .decimalPad
        tf.performableActions = []

        return tf

    // `GRADEDISPLAY_MAX_WIDTH` is referenced in the `.gradeField` 
    // and `.fractionField` cases just above here
    case .allPurpose: return makeTextField(with: params)

    case .allPurposeInsetting: return makeInsetTextField(with: params as! ITParams)
    }
}
```

Line 5: I think this is the initialization of `GRADEDISPLAY_MAX_WIDTH` because `DimensionConstants.swift:220` is where its property definition begins

```
let GRADEDISPLAY_MAX_WIDTH: CGFloat = {

    let gradeField = TF.manufacture(for: .allPurpose, with: TParams(text: "100%", textSize: 17))

    // From the look of the crash report, it doesn't look 
    // like execution makes it this far
    let trailingMargin: CGFloat = 4

    return proportionedWidth(gradeField.frame.size.width + trailingMargin)
}()
```

I'm not sure what Line 4 is referring to. Could it be `GRADEDISPLAY_MAX_WIDTH` itself?

And finally the last reference to my code in the crash report.

Line 3: Which just appears to be the same as Line 8...

The priority here is fixing the crash, and I think it has something to do with what's going on on Lines 6 and 7 of the stack trace. I could get into my code base, but take my word for it that `GRADEDISPLAY_MAX_WIDTH` is not referenced anywhere in `EditClassView` or any code that is related to it, so there's no reason it should be seen anywhere remotely near `EditClassView` in any stack trace.

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on on Lines 6 and 7?

This may be another clue:

On Line 36 in Thread 0 `PercentBasedUnequalField` is referenced; specifically line 12 in it. `PercentBasedUnequalField` is actually not used anywhere within the executing code of the app. It's part of a new feature I'm working on. I left the file in the bundle because it would have been a hassle to remove it because the current source branch branched off that incomplete feature.

The similarity here is that like `GRADEDISPLAY_MAX_WIDTH`, `PercentBasedUnequalField` is also referenced in an unrelated `switch` case in `TF.manufacture(for:with:)`.

### Update

Found [this similar issue](https://github.com/ReSwift/ReSwift/issues/301) where the poster indicates all the `cases` of a `switch` statement are being executed as a swift optimization. That would explain why `GRADEDISPLAY_MAX_WIDTH` is being initialized even though the `case` that accesses it isn't matched. I'll try adding the optimization disabling annotation mentioned in the link and update if it fixes the issue.

Comment: What is TextFieldFactory.swift line 13.  It looks like you are getting a recursive call to a `dispatch_once` block.  It is probably a Swift bug, but you need to work out what is triggering it so you can work around it.  There are some hits on that exception related to `UIFont`

Comment: @Paulw11 That's the definition of the `TParams` typealias: `typealias TParams = TextFieldFactory.TextFieldParams`

Comment: From looking at it some more, you  reference to `GRADEDISPLAY_MAX_WIDTH` has caused a recursive call to `TF.manufacture`.  This is a bad thing™

Comment: @Paulw11 where do you see the cause?

Comment: Well, it seems to be causing a recursive invocation of a dispatch_once block.

Comment: @Paulw11 Right, but nothing in `GRADEDISPLAY_MAX_WIDTH's` definition should be causing that. The whole definition is right there. And the question as to why this property is even showing in the stack trace to begin with is still a mystery. It's not accessed anywhere in the code leading up to it. All the code is there in the post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171659/discussion-between-paulw11-and-shoe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, one compile time optimization that was being done by swift was causing all `cases` in a `switch` statement to be executed, regardless of the matching pattern. This was causing one of my global constants to get initialized cause that's where it happened to be accessed for the first time, and this somehow caused some recursion, if I'm correctly interpreting the `Application Specific Information` in the crash report:

> BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBDISPATCH: trying to lock recursively

I fixed the problem by setting the optimization level to none for releases in `Target` -> `Build Settings` -> `Swift Compiler - Code Generation` -> `Optimization Level` -> `Release`.

So in the end the setting for both release and debug was `-Onone`.

Comment: I don't know why the hell this optimization causes the crash but turning it off for release target worked for me. But I guess it's not good to turn off the default optimization recomended by apple. @shoe, do you have done any research about this?

Comment: @Rendel Where have you seen Apple recommend using the Swift optimizations?

Comment: Saying recommendation I mean that the optimization is turned on by default in build settings so I guess it means that apple recommends to optimize swift code

Comment: @Rendel Even if they do, there's a difference between recommending something beneficial and recommending something that avoids completely breaking your app. I imagine if it were the latter, Apple would've made it clear. Without that warning, I presume it's the former. In which case, foregoing them shouldn't result in anything negative happening; just your app *maybe* running slower. In my case I don't even recall the difference being perceptible.